# how to create sql compact database using visual studio 2015 rc?

Tags: sql-server-ce, visual-studio-2015

i want to create SQL compact database using visual studio 2015 RC
i tried to install SQL compact tools but the problem still exist

the SQL compact option doesn't appear while trying to add a database
any help please?

Answer (score 2):

Install my free SQL Server Compact Toolbox addin, and also install the required SQL Compact runtime if not already installed.